# Should I stop GYM?

Tags: weightlifting, muscle, gym, body-fat

I am 31 man, doing gym 3 to 4 times per week (sometimes 5) every session is about 1hour, and mostly during my lunch break.

My goal was to loose weight and gain muscle as I was (and still) a real skinny fat.

I started gym 1 year and a half ago, and results are no good, as I do not see progression in shoulders and arms for example..

My program is : cardio (running or biking 15min) I do it on HIIT way : 30 seconds fast, 30 slow.. and gym exercises (a muscle group per session) and I use dumbbells for shoulders and chest.

I also do "full body" training, my coach was always saying I have a great cardio.

I perform squat good, and if I can speak about results I need to say that only my legs changed (Gain big muscle but also fat..)

My nutrition (in general) : 3 eggs + greek yogurt with oat in morning / rice with chicken at 12 / chicken or ham at night with vegetables

Before being motivated to change my body I really hated my fat hips, and super thin legs and arms, but now I have bigger hips and not that much biceps, shoulders...

Should I come back to normal nutrition (less calories) and no gym at all?

Comment: It's really hard to judge yourself. Get a second opinion from your partner or a good friend. You won't get huge without drugs anyway and your arms and shoulders will not grow much in just a year. Could you add numbers to your progression in strength? By how much did your lifts increase? A muscle group per session sounds terribly dated, please include your full routine with how much you increase the weight in what interval. You will not gain muscle mass like superman or the terminator in like a couple of months, but maybe there is a chance for you to he more effective and efficient

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a lot to address here, so I will try to do it step-wise.

> I started gym 1 year and a half ago, and results are no good, as I do not see progression in shoulders and arms for example..

Usually if you don't see any progression in a certain part of the body, it's simply because the routine you had wasn't conducive to growth in that particular area. In this case, if your shoulders didn't grow at all, it would be sensible to re-evaluate your program with a trained professional, and have them lay out a complete program for you.

> My program is : cardio (running of biking 15min) I do it on HIIT way : 30 seconds fast, 30 slow.. and gym exercices (a muscle group per session) and I use dumbbells for shoulders and chest.

One muscle group per session seems like a mis-step. One rule of thumb you should adhere to, is to train every single muscle group at least twice a week. Since you train one muscle group per session, and train 3-4 times per week, that seems like a lot of waiting time for each muscle group.

HIIT training is a great way to build cardio and explosive strength at the same time. But I would caution against doing it *before* the weight training. A warmup for lifting weights should be a mild, gradual thing.

> Should I come back to normal nutrition (less calories) and no gym at all ?

This all depends on your goals. Gaining or losing fat is done in the kitchen. It comes down to what you eat. But gaining muscle has to be done by training. A good diet won't build muscle unless you cause a need for repair in muscle tissue.

In summary, it sounds like you would benefit from getting a personal trainer to help you set up a workout program, and a meal plan, with your specific current measurements and goals in mind.